# Изменение размера map

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> Мяч находится на игровом поле m на n в ячейке (i, j), его
>   можно передвигать Найдите количество возможных путей вывода мяча за
>   пределы игрового поля из исходного состояния не более чем за k шагов.
>   Нет ограничения на посещение одной и той же точки несколько раз. То
>   есть при большом k одна и та же клетка может быть пройдена несколько
>   раз.

Необходимо написать алгоритм поиска количества путей из заданной позиции за пределы поля. Используя map в двумерном массиве сохраняю количество путей из конкретной позиции при конкретном количестве оставшихся доступных шагов. Но при рекурсивном вызове функции размер map без причины увеличивается до максимального. Не могу понять из-за чего такое происходит ибо на плюсах программировал не много.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <omp.h>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
struct MyStruct
{
    std::map<int,int> ok;
};
int ik, jk, nk, mk, kk;
int rec(int m, int n, int k,int i, int j,int result, MyStruct *arr ) {
    auto itMap = arr->ok.begin();
    if (i<0 || j<0 || i==m || j==n) {
        result += 1;
        return result;
    }
if (k==0) {
    return 0;
}
k = k - 1;
if (arr[(i+1)*mk+j].ok.count(k)==0) {
    result += rec(m, n, k, i + 1, j, 0, arr);
    arr[(i + 1)*mk + j].ok.insert(std::pair<int, int>(k, result));
}
else
{
    for (itMap= arr[(i + 1)*mk + j].ok.begin(); itMap != arr[(i + 1)*mk + j].ok.end(); itMap++) {
        if (itMap->first == k) {
            result += itMap->second;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (arr[(i)*mk + j+1].ok.count(k) == 0) {
    result += rec(m, n, k, i, j + 1, 0, arr);
    arr[(i)*mk + j+1].ok.insert(std::pair<int, int>(k, result));
}
else
{
    for (itMap = arr[(i)*mk + j+1].ok.begin(); itMap != arr[(i )*mk + j+1].ok.end(); itMap++) {
        if (itMap->first == k) {
            result += itMap->second;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (arr[(i - 1)*mk + j].ok.count(k) == 0) {
    result += rec(m, n, k, i - 1, j, 0, arr);
    arr[(i - 1)*mk + j].ok.insert(std::pair<int, int>(k, result));
}
else
{
    for (itMap = arr[(i - 1)*mk + j].ok.begin(); itMap != arr[(i - 1)*mk + j].ok.end(); itMap++) {
        if (itMap->first == k) {
            result += itMap->second;
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (arr[(i)*mk + j - 1].ok.count(k) == 0) {
    result += rec(m, n, k, i, j - 1, 0, arr);
    arr[(i)*mk + j - 1].ok.insert(std::pair<int, int>(k, result));
}
else
{
    for (itMap = arr[(i)*mk + j - 1].ok.begin(); itMap != arr[(i)*mk + j - 1].ok.end(); itMap++) {
        if (itMap->first == k) {
            result += itMap->second;
            break;
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
void main() {
std::cout.precision(10);
int result;
double start_time, end_time;
std::ifstream fin("input.txt");
while (!fin.eof()) {
    start_time = omp_get_wtime();
    fin >> mk>>nk>>kk>>ik>>jk;
    MyStruct *arr=new MyStruct[nk*mk];
    result = 0;
    result=rec(mk,nk,kk, ik, jk,0,arr);
    end_time = omp_get_wtime();
    std::cout << "m=" << mk << " n=" << nk << " k=" << kk << " i=" << ik;
    std::cout << " j=" << jk << " result=" << result << " time=" << end_time - start_time << std::endl;
    for (int count = 0; count < mk; count++)
        delete[]arr;
}
fin.close();
std::system("pause");
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а можете написать исходную задачу? Если я правильно понимаю,вы пытаетесь реализовать поиск в глубину. Скорее всего проблема в том, что нету проверки от возврата в уже посещённую клетку. Однако код крайне большой для такой задачи.

Comment: Условие: Мяч находится на игровом поле m на n в ячейке (i, j), его можно передвигать 
 Найдите количество возможных путей вывода мяча за пределы игрового поля из исходного 
 состояния не более чем за k шагов. Нет ограничения на посещение одной и той же точки несколько раз. То есть при большом k одна и та же клетка может быть пройдена несколько раз.

Comment: В общем логика неправильная. XY проблема как говорится) ограничения m и n  скажите. Причина так расти у него есть. Правда всё равно он тут не нужен.

Comment: Из ограничений есть ограничение по времени O(m * n * k) и n>0, m>0. В чем конкретно логика не правильная?

Comment: сейчас ответ напишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, рекурсивное решение здесь нельзя использовать. Рост числа элементов экспоненциальный (несколько доказать ну или проверить). Эта задача решается с помощью динамического программирования.

Формула

```
F[s][i][j] := число способов пройти от стартовой точки к {i,j} за s шагов.
{i,j} \in [0,N)*[0,M)   s \in [0,K]

База
F[0][ i][ j] = 0
F[0][x0][y0] = 1

Пересчёт

F[s+1][i][j] = F[s][i-1][j-1] +  F[s][i-1][j+1] + F[s][i+1][j-1] + F[s][i+1][j+1]

если элемента нету, то считаем равным 0.

Ответ - накопительные выходы за границы.
```

Примерный код на слоях (чисто для понимания, не факт что компилируется). Константы размера потом подберёте, например 10000.

```
/**
  @params N,M - размер
  @params x0,y0 - начальная точка
  @params K - число шагов
  @output  - ответ
*/
long long DP[2][maxN][maxM];  //fill 0

#define get(s,i,j) ((i < N && j < M && i>=0 && j>= 0)? DP[s][i][j]:0)     

long long calc(int N, int M, int x0, int y0, int K){
   long long ans = 0;
   DP[0][x0][y0] = 1;
   for (int k=1;k <= K; k++){
      int pr = k&1;
      int r = 1 - pr;

      for (int i=0;i < N; i++) //границы к ответу   
         ans += DP[r][i][0] + DP[r][i][M-1];
      for (int j=0;i < M; j++) //границы к ответу   
         ans += DP[r][0][j] + DP[r][N-1][j];
      for (int i=0; i < N; i++)
         for (int j=0; j < M; j++)
             DP[pr][i][j] =  get(r,i-1,j-1) + get(r,i-1,j+1) 
                           + get(r,i+1,j-1) + get(r,i+1,j+1);
      memset(DP[r], 0 ,sizeof(DP[r]));
   }
   return ans;
}
```

Сложность `O(nmk)` по времени `O(nm)` по памяти.

В теории задача может быть сжата до формул (весьма громоздких), но это уже выходит за рамки вопроса.

P.S. memset в конце можно не вызывать, оставил чтобы меньше вопросов было. Он ни на что не влияет (но это не сразу очевидно).